# If two divs are showing (and only if they are both showing) push text up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am currently working on a website and I have several titles. When I click on a title it shows images below, but when I click in two or more titles everything goes to the wrong place, the whole page gets messed up.
I am trying to fix it with an if statement but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the javascript that I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $(".close1").toggle();
        $("#button2").toggleClass("movedown");
        $(".tab").toggleClass("movetab");
        $(".me").toggleClass("moveme");
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $(".close2").toggle();
        $("#button3").toggleClass("movedown");
        $(".tab").toggleClass("movetab");
        $(".me").toggleClass("moveme");
    });

    $("#button3").click(function(){
        $(".close3").toggle();
        $("#button4").toggleClass("movedown");
        $(".tab").toggleClass("movetab");
        $(".me").toggleClass("moveme");
    });

    $("#button4").click(function(){
        $(".close4").toggle();
        $("#button5").toggleClass("movedown");
        $(".tab").toggleClass("movetab");
        $(".me").toggleClass("moveme");
    });

    $("#button5").click(function(){
        $(".close5").toggle();
        $("#button6").toggleClass("movedown");
        $(".tab").toggleClass("movetab");
        $(".me").toggleClass("moveme");
    });

    $("#button6").click(function(){
        $(".close6").toggle();
    });  

    if ((document.getElementById('#info4').display === 'block') &&
        (document.getElementById('#info5').display === 'block')) {
        $(".me").toggleClass("moveme2");
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: you must add the relative html that is used with the script

Comment: Your `if` statement is inside `$.ready`. I suspect you wanted to have it inside a click handler?

Answer (score 1):

Put this outside of .ready function

```
if ((document.getElementById('#info4').display === 'block') &&
    (document.getElementById('#info5').display === 'block')) {
    $(".me").toggleClass("moveme2");
}
else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: when I put it outside the ready function I can't seem to open the divs, any of them. Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rita24/jdbgw8u3/1/